# get specific key-value pairs from firebase using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a 1000s of documents of products in my firebase db. To show product list in front end I need to get only few key-values of every document. Is it possible to do it in firebase using Node.js. Below is structure of my document.

```
{
  "name":"Prod 1",
  "color" : "red",
  "price" : 1234,
  "sku"  : 156986325,
  "stock" : 20
},
{
  "name":"Prod 2",
  "color" : "black",
  "price" : 1236,
  "sku"  : 896532,
  "stock" : 10
},
{
  "name":"Prod 3",
  "color" : "green",
  "price" : 129,
  "sku"  : 8965324546,
  "stock" : 16
}
```

In this document I need only `"name"`, `"price"` and `"stock"` details as response. Does firebase has this feature? if so then could you help me with the query structure.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Data structure

Firstly, as you are using the Firebase Realtime Database, I would restructure your database to not use arrays. Using arrays will slow down queries and is slower than assigning each product an ID. In your data, you would use the SKU as the ID for each product. Like this:

```
{
  "products": {
    "156986325": {
      "name": "Prod 1",
      "color": "red",
      "price": 1234,
      "stock": 20
    },
    "896532": {
      "name": "Prod 2",
      "color": "black",
      "price": 1236,
      "stock": 10
    },
    "8965324546": {
      "name": "Prod 3",
      "color": "green",
      "price": 129,
      "stock": 16
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

The Firebase Realtime Database does not have the ability to do SQL-like SELECT statements. You will get all the data for the requested keys. Because of this, I would split the data up into separate trees. Like this:

```
{
  "productDetail": {
    "156986325": {
      "name": "Prod 1",
      "color": "red",
      "price": 1234
    },
    "896532": {
      "name":"Prod 2",
      "color" : "black",
      "price" : 1236
    },
    "8965324546": {
      "name":"Prod 3",
      "color" : "green",
      "price" : 129
    }
  },
  "productOrdering": {
    "156986325": {
      "supplier": "...",
      "cost": 549,
      "backorders": 0,
      "stock": 20
    },
    "896532": {
      "supplier": "...",
      "cost": 480,
      "backorders": 0,
      "stock": 10
    },
    "8965324546": {
      "supplier": "...",
      "cost": 99,
      "backorders": 0,
      "stock": 16
    }
  }
}
```

### Example Code

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

This means that you can query for your product list, and then on item detail pages, get more information on the product. Because a human won't need your entire database of products at once, paginate your data.

```
admin.database().ref("productDetail").limitToFirst(20).startAt(0).once("value")
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((productSnapshot) => {
      let sku = productSnapshot.key;
      let data = productSnapshot.val();

      // TODO: Do something with product data
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // TODO: Log/report error
  });
```

To lookup details for a given SKU, use:

```
admin.database().ref("productDetail").child(sku).once("value")
  .then((productSnapshot) => {
    if (!productSnapshot.exists()) {
      // TODO: Handle unknown SKU
    }

    let data = productSnapshot.val();
    // TODO: Do something with data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // TODO: Log/report error
  });
```

**Note:** In `startAt(v)`, `v` is not an index, but a key name. So to get the next page of items, `v` would be the SKU of the last item of the previous page plus 1.

If you intend on doing "advanced" searches (e.g. all products that are red and are also under $100), consider migrating to [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) due to it's ability to filter data on multiple properties at once.

Comment: Thank you. this was helpful. do we have SQL-like SELECT statements in cloud firestore?

Comment: Unfortunately not. In Cloud Firestore, everything is contained in "documents" which are kind of like shallow objects. They can refer to other documents, but they don't have to be downloaded when you want information for just the document and not it's children. I recommend looking into the [Firecasts on Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ) for more info.